# Has an $m \times n$ matrix with the property of swapping $a_{ij}$ and $a_{i(n - j +1)}$ any interesting properties?

Tags: matrices

I was wondering if a matrix $A$ with dimensions $m \times n$ has a property (similar to transposition)
where we define a new matrix $B$ with:
$$
b_{ij} = a_{i(n-j+1)}
$$
For example if we have:
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}3 & 2 & 1 \\ 6 & 1 & 4 \\ 4 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}
$$
then:
$$
B =\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 \\ 4 & 1 & 6 \\ 1 & 0 & 4\end{pmatrix}
$$

Does the matrix $B$ (given some $A$ that isn't the zero matrix) have any properties that are the same as in $A$? One can for example tell that $\text{Col } A = \text{Col } B$, but what about determinants? Is $B$ invertible if $A$ is?

And if so, why?

Comment: We will have $|\det(A)|=|\det(B)|$ assuming $m=n$ , also $rank(A)=rank(B)$. I think, there are more properties.

Comment: If $m=n$, we also have that $A$ is invertible if and only if $B$ is.